# Restart code in Python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a python project for school and I want to restart my program when a user enters a certain input. How would I do that? Here is my code:

```
num1 = int(input('What is 5+5? '))
true = int('10')
if num1 == true:
    print ('Correct!')
else:
    print ('Nope, not quite!')
```

I want the whole code to restart if the user does not print "10", so I want it to restart and ask what 5+5 is again if the user enters the wrong answer. Can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Just wrap it all in a loop and execute a `continue`.

Comment: Not this again... What is wrong with **simply copy-pasting** the code? It makes the code searchable, easy to copy-past, uses less bandwidth, can be read by a screenreader for the visual less talented,...

Comment: sorry my computer messed it up. Code should be there now

Comment: It's a bad idea to use `true`  as a variable name. Because `True` is a keyword for the Boolean True value.

Comment: You don't need to use `true = int('10')` to store the integer 10 in a variable, you can simply do `true = 10`

Comment: You don't need to have the value 10 in a variable to compare it in the if-statement, you can simply do: `if num1 == 10:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    num1 = int(input('What is 5+5? '))
    result = int('10')
    if num1 == result:
        print ('Correct!')
        break
    else:
        print ('Nope, not quite!')
```

Wrap it in a while loop. Or a for-loop if you want it to repeat a special number of times.

Comment: If that helps you, accept the answer. That's how stackoverflow works ;)